# Float values dividing error in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

When I run this block of code :

```
float angle = startAngle;
int i = 0;

for (float f = self.minNumber; f <= self.maxNumber; f += minorTickIncrement) {
    points[i++] = CGPointMake(centerX + cos(angle) * (radius - tickInset), centerY + sin(angle) * (radius - tickInset));

    CGFloat myTickLength;

    NSLog(@"f : %f",f);
    NSLog(@"tickIncrement : %f",tickIncrement);
    NSLog(@"f / tickIncrement : %f",f / tickIncrement);
    NSLog(@"(int)(f / tickIncrement) : %d",(int)(f / tickIncrement));
    NSLog(@"(f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : %f",(f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)));
    NSLog(@"fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : %f",fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))));

    float checkValue = (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement));

    if (fabs(checkValue) < 0.05) { // if is major tick
        myTickLength = self.tickLength;
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.1f", f];
        float textWidth = textHeight * [string length] / 2;
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, centerX + cos(angle) * (radius - textInset) - textWidth / 2.0, centerY + sin(angle) * (radius - textInset) + textHeight / 4.0, [string UTF8String], [string length]);
        [string release];

    } else {
        myTickLength = self.minorTickLength;
    }

    points[i++] = CGPointMake(centerX + cos(angle) * (radius - myTickLength - tickInset), centerY + sin(angle) * (radius - myTickLength - tickInset));

    angle += minorTickAngleIncrement;
}
```

The following output is been displayed :

```
 f : 0.100000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 1.000000
 (int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 0.000000
  fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 0.000000

  f : 0.120000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 1.200000
 (int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 0.200000
 fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 0.200000

 f : 0.140000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 1.400000
 (int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 0.400000
 fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 0.400000

 f : 0.160000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 1.600000
 (int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 0.600000
 fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 0.600000

 f : 0.180000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 1.800000
 (int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 0.800000
 fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 0.800000

 f : 0.200000
 tickIncrement : 0.100000
 f / tickIncrement : 2.000000
 **(int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1**
 (f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement)) : 1.000000
 fabs((f / tickIncrement - (int)(f / tickIncrement))) : 1.000000

...................
```

Where, you can see that in the last block of output `(int)(f / tickIncrement) : 1` must return 2, but instead it returns 1.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you're running into floating point representation problems.
Try using a double, but know that it isn't going to solve the underlying problem, that the `2.0` you see is actually `1.99999 ...` that is simply getting formatted to show `2.0`

Read "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)"

In the meantime, try simply using:

```
(int)(f / tickIncrement + tickIncrement / 5.0)
```